# Writing to a text file in python

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
count=0
counter=0
score=0
function=['+','x','-']

print('Welcome To The Arithmetic Quiz!')
name=input('Please enter you name:')
print('Thanks' , name , 'Lets Get Started!')

time.sleep(1)
while counter <10:
    firstnumber=random.randint(0,12)
    secondnumber=random.randint(0,6)
    operator=random.choice(function) 

    question=print(firstnumber, operator, secondnumber, '=')
    Answer = input('Answer:')


    if operator== '+':
                    count=firstnumber+secondnumber
                    if count == int (Answer):
                        print ('Correct!')
                        score= score+1
                    else:
                        print ('Incorrect!')
    elif operator== 'x':
                    count=firstnumber*secondnumber
                    if count == int (Answer):
                        print ('Correct!')
                        score= score+1
                    else:

                        print ('Incorrect!')
    elif operator== '-':
                    count=firstnumber-secondnumber
                    if count == int (Answer):
                        print ('Correct!')
                        score= score+1
                    else:

                        print ('Incorrect!')

    counter += 1

    time.sleep(0.5)

print('Well Done' ,name,'! You Scored',score ,'Out of 10!')


f = open("Test Scores.txt","a") 
f.write(name)
f.write(' ')
f.write('%d' % score)
f.close()
```

The last section of code should write the person's name and score in a text file. 
It does this perfectly well, but I would like it to write on a new line each time (not on the same line like it does now).

Comment: OK, so... what have you tried to that end? Have you considered adding in a newline `'\n'`?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
f.write(name + '\n')
```

instead of

```
f.write(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you write something, you can insert a newline token `\n` at the end. It will insert a new line for you.

```
f.write(something + '\n') # Adds a new line at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a definition to write a file away.

```
def writeFile(value): 
    open('file.txt', 'a') as file 
    file.write(value)
    file.write('\n')
```

To use it you only need to call this definition. 
Everything you write will end up on a new line, becasue of the '\n'.

```
writeFile('HelloWorld')
```